# How do I get it this component to load the Edit Page component

Tags: reactjs

In the code below, I am trying to get my component, `<Page>`, to return the `<EditPage>` component when the user has created a page. However, the render method always returns the `<CreatePage>` component even after the state contains all the data for the edit page component.

```
class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.authenticated = props.authenticated;
    this.state = {
      page: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    let config = null;
    let token = null;
    const current = this;

    app
      .auth()
      .currentUser.getIdToken(true)
      .then(function(idToken) {
        token = idToken;
        config = {
          headers: { Authorization: idToken }
        };

        console.log(config);

        axios
          .get('http://localhost:4001/api/v1/user/page', config)
          .then(res => {
            const page = res.data;

            if (_.isEmpty(page)) {
              current.setState({ empty: 'empty' });
            } else {
              current.setState(page);
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {});
      });
  };

  render() {
    if (_.isEmpty(this.state.page)) {
      return <CreatePage />;
    } else {
      return <EditPage />;
    }
  }
}

export default Page;
```

Comment: what does your page state look like after it comes back from server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the code to setState should look like this because you are checking against page inside your state object.

```
current.setState({ page })
```

Comment: thank you so much , How did you learn react. Need need some better resources than what I am using.

Comment: I think reactjs.org has some good resources for starting. I learned mostly by doing. Dont worry too much, making mistakes will help you learning better